# Appending a list of tuples into another list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Not sure if there are dupes since I don't see any in similar situations as mine. Apologise if there are dupes!
I have a list of tuples `a = [(1,4,5), (3,1,2)]` and `b = [(7,5,3), (2,6,8)]`. I'd like to append a to b to make a single list of tuples. Is that possible or do I have to go the long way of converting both into lists and appending them?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: `b = b + a` should do the job..

Comment: oh that's so simple! thank you :)

Comment: I have added an answer with two possible ways :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in either of the following ways:

```
b = b + a   # using the concatenation operator

b.extend(a) # Using extend() method
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend a with b

```
a += b
```

This is just syntactic sugar for

```
a.extend(b)
```

if you wanted to keep both original lists intact you could assign to a new var

```
c = a + b
```